# Why does a DBI ODBC connection tell me CoInitialize has not been called?

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, dbi

I'm connecting to an Azure SQL box, and have not had issues with it for months. Today, I get this error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: FA004: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server][Failed to authenticate user '' in Active Directory (Auth option is 'Active Directory Integrated')
Error code 0x800401F0; state 10
CoInitialize has not been called.
```

The error code seems to be something with COM in Windows.

I guess what I'm asking is this: Does this error stem from an issue in R, or an issue with permissions in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that stumble on this, I needed to update base R and install the requisite packages (DBI). That seemed to fix the error.

Comment: you can accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I won't forget next time. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Uninstalling and Reinstalling the DBI package (ver 1.1.0) got it working again.

---

I'm still fighting the exact same error message myself, connecting to Azure Sql Server using Azure Active Directory Integrated Authentication. Running Windows 10.

Getting same error as OP, upgraded drivers & libraries, rebooted.  For a few hours it did work, now back to this same error. I can connect with SSMS. I can do "Test Connection" in the ODBC and it works.

The fact that it worked for a little while is really throwing me, like something timed out somewhere?

ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, version 2017.174.02.0
R (base): 3.6.2
odbc: 1.2.2
DBI: 1.1.0

Any ideas about what to look for or try greatly appreciated!

p.s. Not sure if best practice is to create new question or add on to this on. Since my error message is identical, I didn't want to create a duplicate either :-/

Comment: Heyo, welcome to SO. Sorry you are stuck on the same problem, but this doesn't fit the [criteria for an 'answer'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you @Nate for the guidance! I agree it's not an answer, what is the best way to ask the same question? In comments instead?